# trying to build a multi dimensional array a-z 0-9 2 levels deep

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build an array that is a-z, 0-9 and each one of those has a sub set of the same array.

IE:

```
array(
   "a"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
   "b"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
   "c"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
   "d"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
   "0"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
   "1"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
   "2"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
   "3"=>array("a","b","c"..."0","1","2")
)
```

Where I am trying this

```
$finalArr = array();
$letterArr = range('a', 'z');
$numericArr = range(0,9);
$startArr = array_merge($letterArr, $numericArr);

foreach($startArr as $key => $val)
{
    $finalArr[$val] = $startArr;
    foreach($finalArr[$val] as $key2 => $val2)
    {
        $finalArr[$val][$val2] = $startArr;
    }


}
```

But it only works on the first pass... after that it just starts making a mess. Any Idea's?

Comment: I think this line is doing all you want and no need to write second foreach `$finalArr[$val] = $startArr;`

Comment: In case you want all the letters and numbers as keys of your resulting array (and not only the first four as in the example), @Akam is right: http://codepad.viper-7.com/s7hPfN ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying the array as you loop over it; this is not a good practice, and in this case it's not even necessary.

That said, you can just use [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys) like this:

```
$arr = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789');
$final = array_fill_keys($arr, $arr);
```

Comment: This isn't for everyday use, this is for something of a maintenance issue I am running into overall I have several folders within folders within folders that follow this schema, for harvesting images from my users so I don't run into indexing slow down as frequently by dummping them into a single directory. But on the occasion things expire if you will call it that and I clean up. I also on the occasion have to recreate the folder structure on a new server so, good/bad practice is not something Im concerned about with this in particular, its just a dirty method of handling something :-)

Comment: @chris Bad practice was just part of the argument, the other was that it's not necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used the same array name under inner loop

```
foreach($finalArr[$val] as $key2 => $val2)
    {
        $finalArr[$val][$val2] = $startArr;
    }
```

Declare a new array $finalArr2 = array() and change the code to

```
foreach($finalArr[$val] as $key2 => $val2)
    {
        $finalArr2[$val][$val2] = $startArr;
    }
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

To use your existing logic you need to `unset($finalArr[$val][$key2]);` to clear out the array you have temporally stored.

```
$finalArr = array();
$letterArr = range('a', 'z');
$numericArr = range(0,9);
$startArr = array_merge($letterArr, $numericArr);

foreach($startArr as $key => $val)
{
    $finalArr[$val] = $startArr;
    foreach($finalArr[$val] as $key2 => $val2)
    {
        unset($finalArr[$val][$key2]);
        $finalArr[$val][$val2] = $startArr;
    }    
}
```

If you want some cleaner logic, this makes a lot more sense.

```
foreach($startArr as $val)
{
    foreach($startArr as $val2)
    {                                 
        $finalArr[$val][$val2] = $startArr;
    }
}
```